# Naming secondary amine IUPAC system

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

$\ce{CH3NHCH(CH3)CH2CH3}$
Should this be named as 2-(N-methyl)butanamine or 2-(methylamino)butane?

In other words, do we name the compound as 'alkanamine' or treat amino group as a substituent of butane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be N-methyl-2-butanamine. Amine is treated as a functional group attached. So we write it as alkanamine as it is the only functional group here.

[image]

Image source: [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.99670.html)

Comment: Note that the preferred IUPAC name for the compound drawn is in fact slightly different from what you have written: it should be ***N*-methylbutan-2-amine**. In particular the locant '2' should be placed immediately before the suffix 'amine', and the locant '*N*' should be italicised.